# Grub command showing on system boot

Tags: grub2

I installed Windows on dual boot machine with Ubuntu, so I lost Ubuntu.

I wanted to get that dual screen boot menu back so just followed this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

and as explained, I executed the command

`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/0d104aff-ec8c-44c8-b811-92b993823444 /dev/sda`

instead of

`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/0d104aff-ec8c-44c8-b811-92b993823444 /dev/sda6`

On booting, my machine shows the screen with Grub commands like:

Grub>_

Please help me. What should I do? I think I installed grub on /dev/sda instead of /dev/sda6.

How do I remove grub from `/dev/sda`?

**SOLUTION:** I did not read the above link completely, At the end of the page it is mentioned what should be done in this particular case. I just used Ubuntu 9.04 Live CD and got it working..Thanks every one for ur time.

Comment: You used the same UUID as in the example. Is the uuid really correct?

Comment: The target device `/dev/sda` is ok, if you have only one disk, but the UUID of the root partition is surely wrong, because is the same that appears in the help page. You have to determine your particulare UUID following the instructions in the help page.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, perhaps you should run the `sudo update-grub` or `sudo update-grub2` command. That will likely look for the bootable systems in your computer and add them to the grub list.

I think it should be in the `/dev/sda`, isn't that your primary partition?

Comment: I tried the command `sudo update-grub` but it keep saying `/usr/sbin/grub-probe:error: cannot find a device for /(is /dev mounted?)`